# The browser makes 4 requests when sending data to the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch, navigator

I am having problems with my react component. The problem is that when I want to get the current geographic coordinates, I get them 4 times. The same problem persists if I submit them to the server. The browser makes 4 identical requests instead of one. What could be wrong? This is the complete code for my component:

```
import React from "react";

export const Component = (): JSX.Element => {
  const getCoords = async (): Promise<GeolocationPosition> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position: GeolocationPosition) => resolve(position),
        (error) => reject(error)
      );
    });
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = (await getCoords()).coords;
    console.log(latitude + " " + longitude);
    const response = await fetch(`URL`);
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  };

  getData();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you have 4 of this component on the page?

Comment: Well first, your `getCoords()` function does not need to make its own Promise; the geolocation API already makes one for you, and you can just `await` that and return the result. Also, your `getData()` function is marked `async`, but it doesn't return anything and when it's called it's called without `await` or `.then()`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes

Comment: @Arew: well, there you go, mystery solved.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So this is just a rerender or something?

Comment: No, just regular render. Try to leave only one instance on the page and see if requests are still duplicated.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well, unfortunately it is still duplicated. Even when I completely removed other components.

Comment: This sounds unlikely. Can you cook up a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com) or a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.com) or something? Maybe even a code snippet here (it should be able to handle react, at a glance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call API in the body ò function component. You should call `getData` in the `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getCoords = async (): Promise<GeolocationPosition> => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position: GeolocationPosition) => resolve(position),
          (error) => reject(error)
        );
      });
    };

    const getData = async () => {
      const { latitude, longitude } = (await getCoords()).coords;
      console.log(latitude + " " + longitude);
      const response = await fetch(`URL`);
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
    };

    getData();
  }, []);
```